# What would be the best way to implement HATEOAS in a spring-boot-starter-web project?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have developed a REST Api using Spring boot. These are the dependencies used as of now:

`spring-boot-starter-parent`, `spring-boot-starter-web`, `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

Now I want to add HATEOAS to my controllers response, but I am bit confused which dependency to use.

1. `spring-hateoas`
2. `spring-boot-starter-hateoas` - Since it's a spring boot project, this would be better choice, I guess
3. `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` - I am quite confused over this since this is a complete Spring project which is used to build REST API(and don't have to worry about HATEOAS). So, why to bring the complete project just for adding HATEOAS.

Could someone please suggest me the best approach to use here?

Also, I am not using `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` to develop the API, as I want the total control over my Controllers. Is my choice over not choosing `data-rest` wise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Spring Boot project use that hateoas starter.

Spring Hateoas provides a collection of components for producing responses that follow the HATEOAS pattern.
Spring Data Rest is a set of components and a controller that will allow for exposing Spring Data Repositories as Rest HATEOAS endpoints. You don't need SDR for HATEOAS.

Comment: thanks. For a complex and large scale website, would you prefer SDR over boot starter? IMHO, it would be more better of controllers are in our hand.

Comment: I prefer to create controllers to do the work needed. If may be worthwhile to use SDR for queries only. Configure it so that only the specifically annotated methods are available from the repositories. Ensure that the relevant controllers have annotations to indicate which resources they serve.